# Dart - How to invoke/call a nullable function object

Tags: flutter, dart

How I call the function `VoidCallback? fun;` which is nullable?

I tried many ways like:

```
fun();       //Error: Can't use an expression of type 'void Function()?' as a function because it's potentially null.
fun?();      //error
fun?.();     //error
fun()?;      //error
```

Comment: `fun?.call()`.  Or, if you can guarantee that `fun` is not `null`: `fun!()`.

Answer (score 2):

Like @jamesdlin commented. You can use `fun?.call()` or check if it is null before using it `if (fun != null) { fun!(); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Function? fun();
```